# Redirecting ASP.Net MVC sub routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I'm trying to redirect my website on azure from the default domain to my personal one. So far I managed to reroute the top level domain, how ever when accessing a page that has parameters i.e. routing it does not seem to work.

Current entry in the Web.config

```
<rule name="redirect azurewebsites calls" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)example.azurewebsites.net(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

So far example.azurewebsites.net is rerouted to example.com, but whenever I try to open example.azurewebsites.net/site/argument it will not get rerouted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `url="http://example.com/{R:1}"`?

Comment: Tried it lead to a 500 error when calling the root node.

Comment: To confirm, you already have a CNAME that points example.com to example.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: @BrendanGreen yes I have a wildcard CNAME configured for the site that points example.com to example.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Please try @l19's comment.  I used extensive url rewriting on my Azure website and am also using `{R:1}`.  According to the docs, `{R:0}` back references to the matched input string, which is not what you want.

Comment: @BrendanGreen thanks, I tried l19's comment but that led to a 500 error on the server... I could not find the documentation could you maybe paste a link? I just don't know what to google for so I'm pretty much lost at the basics...